# why I have different output with `-d filename` and the `d---------`?

Tags: linux, shell

I've written a shell-script to judge how many directory, but when I use regex to grab the `drwxr--r--` or `-d filename`,I get the different output,that's why?

```
echo -n "the amount of dir:"
count=0
for i in $(ls -1 $1)
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        ((count++))
    fi
done
echo "$count"

echo -n "the amount of dir:"
ls -l $1|awk 'BEGIN{count=0;}{if(index($0,"d")==1){count++;}}END{print count;}'
```

and the output:

```
the amount of dir:18
the amount of dir:19
```

the authority is just below, :

```
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x     
drwxr-xr-x  
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x  
drwxr-xr-x   
-rw-r--r--   
-rw-r--r--   
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x
drwxr-xr-x 
drwxr-xr-x  
drwxr-xr-x   
-rw-r--r--  
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x
drwxr-xr-x  
drwxr-xr-x  
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x   
drwxr-xr-x   
-rw-r--r-- 
-rw-r--r--  
-rw-r--r--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `find` Instead of `ls` to Enumerate Directories

[Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Instead, use the `find` utility and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). For example, you could use the following function to print the number of directories in `/tmp` without recursing into its subdirectories:

```
count_directories () {
    count=$(find -L "$1" -type d -maxdepth 1 | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
    echo "Number of directories in $1: $count"
}
```

### Sample Output

```
$ count_directories "/tmp"
Number of directories in /tmp: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this instead?

If you **do not want** to include hidden directories in the count (`./.example/`):

`count=$(find ${1}/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)`

If you **want** to include hidden directories in the count:

`count=$(find ${1} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)`

Comment: `the amount of dir: 14`,it gives me a third answer!that's why?

Comment: Depends if you want to count hidden directories or not (the ones that start with a dot)

Comment: ,but in my code above,you can see I don't use `-al`

Comment: Then you should do a bit of debugging. Try executing those commands (including my suggestion) one by one in the shell, compare with the expected output (check first yourself with `ls -l`) and see which one works, if any

Comment: PS: I've edited my answer to make a clear distinction between including/not-including hidden directories